# Needed XP and Total XP for leveling system, discord.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord.js

I'm building a bot that stores xp for every message entered. I'm good with my needed xp counter for the next level. My question is should I also add a key value pair for **Total XP**? My Mongo doc only stores XP and then once it is equal or greater than the needed XP it increments the level by 1, and then it resets xp to 0 while retaining the extra.

I might need the total XP at some point, so I was wondering whether I should just add a key for it on the Mongo Doc or maybe just query it with math like this:

```
Math.floor(50 * (previous level ^ 2) + xp)
```

Here's my Mongo Document:

```
{
"name": "Ben",
"discordId": "1234567890",
"level": 1,
"xp": 15
}
```

Here's a sample equation:

```
Math.floor(50 * (level ^ 2))
```

**XP needed** to level up from 1 to 5:

1. 50
2. 200
3. 450
4. 800
5. 1250

**Total XP** per level:

1. 50
2. 250
3. 700
4. 1500
5. 2750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one day I made a bot like this and I've seen the XP was broken and people were levelup too quickly.
In that case, I need to change all the ranks manually (Too boring).

So I can recommend you to don't store level / current level xp but store only a key with the totalXP.
And with this totalXP, make a function to "parse" this xp by calculating the actual level.

Example:
I want level up each 200 XP and the user has 860xp.

```js
function convertXP(xp) {
 return { level: Math.floor(xp / 200), xp: xp % 200, totalXP: xp };
}
```

And you'll call this function just after getting the user xp
By example with mongoose:

```js
User.findOne({discordId: user.discordId}, function(err,obj) {
 interaction.reply({content: `You're level ${convertXP(obj.xp).level} with ${convertXP(obj.xp).xp} / 200 for the next level`
});
```